# An if statement condition in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm pulling results into a .csv file through a PowerShell script. Everything seems fine but, one of the record it pulls the values as 6.00000 and 63.00000. These 2 values are of different columns. I would like to see the results of these 2 columns as the rest of the columns just like 6 and 63

I have tried `[math]::Round()`, `Truncate()` and other commands. But it's not working.

```
{
    if ($_.Critical -eq 0 -and $_.High -eq 0 -and $_.Medium -eq 0) {
        'pass'
    } else {
        'fail'
    }
}
[math]::Truncate($_.Critical), [math]::Truncate($_.High), [math]::Truncate($_.Medium)
```

The code above prints pass for all 0's but for fail it prints 6.0000,63.0000 fail. I would like to see the fail results as just 6 & 63.

Comment: Try type-casting them: `[int][Math]::Floor($_)`

Comment: My guess would be that the system has `$_.Critical`,  `$_.High`, and `$_.Medium` as Strings.  You'll need to cast them to a numeric data type. I would recommend Decimal due to it's accuracy and ability to represent decimal values: `[decimal]$_.Critical`.

Comment: Are yo saying that the `[math]::Truncate(...)` calls report numbers with decimal places? They shouldn't. Can you provide example input that produces the symptom?

Comment: This may just be a posting artifact, but just to be clear:  the code in your question doesn't actually _execute_ the `if` statement, because the enclosing stand-alone script block (`{ ... }`) would simply _print its contents_ without invocation via `&` or without being attached to a `ForEach-Object` call.

Comment: Check the decimal symbol used in the CSV file. On my Dutch machine, `[math]::truncate("63,00000")` (using the COMMA) indeed returns 6300000. If that value in the csv is using a decimal POINT like in `[math]::truncate("63.00000")` it gets the wanted result of 63.

Comment: Show us two or three lines of the CSV file. Especially the lines that return the unexpected results. This will probably make things a lot clearer.